# Creating TABCONTAINER with ajax dynamically ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabcontrol, tabpanel, tabcontainer

Within a tabcontainer I wish to  show a variety of tabs which will contain different user controls.
I need to assign the user controls to the tabs through code, and not assign the user controls as its usually done within the tags, for instance:

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="NOMBRE" ID="TabPanel1"  Enabled ="true" >
    <ContentTemplate>

    </ContentTemplate>
</ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

For what I need this does not work.

So here is my code to assign the tabs to the user controls, the code is as the fallowing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
         Control ctrlNombre = LoadControl("~/UserCtrl/Nombre.ascx"); //user control
         TabPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrlNombre);  //add user control to tabpanel     
     }
 }
```

And the event  “onactivetabchanged” I create a menu depending on which tab is active, which will load the control, here is the code:

```
protected void TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex)
    {
         case 0:
             Control ctrl1 = LoadControl("~/UserCtrl/userControl1.ascx");
             TabPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrlNombre);
             break;
          case 1:
             Control ctrl2 = LoadControl("~/UserCtrl/ userControl2.ascx");
            TabPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrlApPaterno);

    }
 }
```

However, this actually does  work, the problem occurs  when  I clicked a certain button from some user control, this makes a full post back to the server as it would normally will do, but this post back causes the user control previously loaded disappear. What can I do to solve this? I really hope someone will help me out on this one, I will really appreciate it.

Here is an image of what happens when I clicked a button:
[image]

Thank you so much guys, I hope someone can help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to recreate the tab panels when the postback occurs in the Page_init because the tabpanels do not exist on post backs until they have been made...

So in Page_init you should call a function that makes the default tab collection and then later on the page you can add a new tab panel to the collection.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Control ctrlNombre = LoadControl("~/UserCtrl/Nombre.ascx"); //user control
     TabPanel1.Controls.Add(ctrlNombre);  //add user control to tabpanel   
}
```

Refer:

http://dorababu-meka.blogspot.com/2012/12/create-dynamical-ajax-tab-and-filling.html
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Ravish001/create-dynamic-tabs-using-ajax-tab-container-add-controls-read-them-dynamically/

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I will try either one of the links you provided and will update you if it helped me solved this issue, and thanks for editing my post, I appreciate it.